# Easy Localization Flutter package

Tags: flutter

I use the easy localization package, how can I check and change the language with just one button?

https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // 'En' 
    // 'Ar'
  },
  child: Text('Switch lang'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have JSON file for changing the language.
if so, simply you need to take the language by calling
`EasyLocalization.of(context)?.locale;`
or after importing EasyLocalization package just write `context.locale;`

For changing use `EasyLocalization.of(context)?.setLocale(Locale('EN'));` or `context.setLocale(Locale('EN'))`;

Comment: Yes I have all that, but I just need to know how to switch between two languages 'ar' , and 'en'

Comment: How to get languages?

Comment: var locale = context.locale == Locale('ar') ? Locale('en') : Locale('ar');
context.setLocale(locale);

Comment: this gives you language `context.locale;`
or this `EasyLocalization.of(context)?.locale;`